# Получить все элементы с максимальной датой

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Модель

```
public class Counter
    {
        public decimal Id { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public int? HousesId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("HousesId")]
        public virtual House House { get; set; }
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ServiceId")]
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PovDate { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CountersData> CountersData { get; set; }
        public int? UnitMeterId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<CountersDataCurrent> CountersDataCurrent { get; set; }
        public Counter()
        {
            CountersDataCurrent = new List<CountersDataCurrent>();
        }
        [ForeignKey("UnitMeterId")]
        public virtual UnitMeter UnitMeter { get; set; }
    }

public class CountersData
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PeriodBeg { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCurrent { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DatePrevious { get; set; }
        public decimal? CurrentValue { get; set; }
        public decimal? PreviousValues { get; set; }
        public decimal? Consumption { get; set; }
        public Int16? zn { get; set; }

        public decimal CounterId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CounterId")]
        public Counter Counters { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо отсортировать CountersData по последнему PeriodBeg и вытащить все последние элементы с этой последней датой

Вот так могу вытащить только с последним значением но нужно именно все последние элементы

```
model.ForEach(x => x.CountersData = x.CountersData
                                            .OrderByDescending(c => c.PeriodBeg)
                                            .Take(1)
                                            .ToList());
```

Подскажите какой фильтр необходимо вставить что бы реализовать мой запрос?

Comment: Используйте [SelectMany](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level2/2_2.php) после `.Take(1)`

Comment: Совсем забыл, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
model.ForEach(x => x.CountersData = x.CountersData
                                          .OrderByDescending(c => c.PeriodBeg)
                                          .Take(1)
                                          .SelectMany(e => x.CountersData
                                                     .Where(eo => eo.PeriodBeg == e.PeriodBeg)).ToList());
```

Comment: а почему не просто `model.ForEach(x => x.CountersData = x.CountersData.OrderByDescending(c => c.PeriodBeg).Take(1).ToList());` ?

Comment: @tym32167 потому что таким образом я заберу лишь один элемент коллекции, а мне нужны все элементы с последней датой